# How swap elements in grid on click without reloading DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, css-grid

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPYppp?&editable=true

```js
jQuery.fn.swap = function(b) {
  b = jQuery(b)[0];
  var a = this[0],
    a2 = a.cloneNode(true),
    b2 = b.cloneNode(true),
    stack = this;

  a.parentNode.replaceChild(b2, a);
  b.parentNode.replaceChild(a2, b);

  stack[0] = a2;
  return this.pushStack(stack);
};

function changeVideos() {
  $('.wrap-grid > div:nth-child(n + 2)').click(function() {
    $('.wrap-grid > div:nth-child(1)').swap($(this));
    $(this).off();
    changeVideos();
  })
};
changeVideos();
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-content .container>.row> :first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-content .container>.row> :last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.wrap-grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "a b" "a c" "a d";
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrap-grid>div {
  position: relative;
}

.wrap-grid iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap-grid>* {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrap-grid> :nth-child(n + 2) iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.wrap-grid> :nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: a;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .wrap-grid {
    grid-template-areas: "a" "b" "c" "d";
  }
  .wrap-grid>* {
    height: 255px;
  }
  .wrap-grid> :nth-child(1) {
    height: 255px;
  }
  .main-content .container>.row> :first-child,
  .main-content .container>.row> :last-child {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-grid">
  <div><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
  <div><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
  <div><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
  <div><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>

</div>
```

[image: grid image example]

I trying to swap one of three elements on right side with element on the left side. Same as in example, where i tried to swap with jquery, but this is reload dom elements and they are blinking. Is there any way to do this with manipulating properties like `order` in `flexbox` or maybe with the `grid` layout.

Comment: First note; don't *only* include a link to a codepen.  Also include the logic in your question.  Don't make helping you harder on those who want to help.  Second note; if you are just wanting to move elements around, don't clone them.  Just move them.

Answer (score 0):

You can access and set their flexbox `order` with plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('your-id').style.order = 2
document.getElementById('your-id').style.order // returns "2"
```

or jQuery:

```
$('#your-id').css('style', 2)
$('#your-id').css('style') // returns "2"
```

Comment: Does changing their style order actually change their position in the DOM?

Comment: I ask this because the logic is using `nth-child` selectors that could be impacted if not.

Comment: that's not working, maybe because layout is grid and left element is now has property `grid-area: a`

Comment: Flexbox `order` does not change their position in the DOM, only how they are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing is you are iframing a video and loading a video into an iframe, that has to reload when you move it.

I would recommend revising the code so that you load the base image as they don't take time to reload compared to a full youtube video.

the cover pic for youtube videos are

```
 <img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg">
```

and for your video, it would be:

```
   <img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/Bey4XXJAqS8/hqdefault.jpg">
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i need to move exactly videos

Comment: you going to get that with videos. now if you use the cover image, it stays in the user cache and doesn't have to make the request. There are several ways to swap the image to play the vid btw...